# Is there an "initial condition" for ARMA model?

Tags: time-series, arma

1. ARMA model is a stochastic version of recursive relation. For
   deterministic recursive relations, we solve them and need initial
   conditions to fully get the solution.  So I wonder what is an "initial
   condition" for ARMA model like?
2. In [Introduction to Time Series and Forecasting, by Peter J.
   Brockwell, Richard A. Davis](http://books.google.com/books?id=VHB4OSAmwcUC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA85#v=onepage&q&f=false), they define an ARMA model to be
   causal, if its output process can  be represented as MA($\infty$)
   (see equation (3.1.5)). In equation (3.1.7), they gave the explicit
   formulation of the MA($\infty$) representation. I don't find they specify or use any "initial" condition in the definition of causality and in the derivation of the
   MA($\infty$) representation.  This is quite different from that we
   need initial conditions to fully get the solution to a deterministic
   recursive relation. So how shall we understand  the MA($\infty$)
   representation of an ARMA output process?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The ARMA model in $MA(\infty)$ representation it is not a full solution. This means that based on $\phi(z)\psi(z)=\theta(z)$ you can only derive the the coefficients of $\psi(z)$, obviously when the ARMA model is causal. A full solution means to find an explicit computable formula, which can't be obtained if you don't assume initial conditions, as you already stated.